# DokuWiki: Side-By-Side diff: Table with two cols in code block in table cell

Tags: dokuwiki

I want to create a table in DokuWiki which has two rows.

On the left side is a code block (old code), and on the right side there is an other code block (new code).

How to format this in dokuwiki?

If it would be html, it would be easy:

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <pre>
   ...
   </pre>
  </td>
  <td>
   <pre>
   ...
   </pre>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Optional: Syntax highlighting for Python would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the work:

```
| <code>Row 1 Col 1</code> | <code>Row 1 Col 2</code> |
```

Or for a simple monospaced text use `''`:

```
| ''%%Row 1 Col 1%%'' | ''%%Row 1 Col 2%%'' |
```

**EDIT** Add `%% %%` makes string to be not interpreted as DokuWiki syntax.

Here the documentation: https://www.dokuwiki.org/wiki:syntax

Answer (score 0):

```
||border=1 
||!Table heading 1||!Table heading 2||
||Cell 1.1||Cell 1.2||
||Cell 2.1||Cell 2.2||
```